# Wi-Fi range issue with new MBA 13 and Netgear WNR 2200 router

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

Loving the new MBA 13 (my first Mac), but running into a frustrating wi-fi issue.

The MBA wi-fi flies when the machine is in the same room as the NetGear WNR2200 router, but it slows down considerably as I move it through our (smallish) house, and it pretty much crawls to a stop just 10 yards or so away from the router.

Original post
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1195289

Plus it does not connect automatically when wakes up.
Found lot's of articles with suggestions reseting from firmware to operating system but non of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I've tried to improve performance switching from 54mb and WPA to 150-300 and WPA2.

Struggled with problems around 6 months and could not get back as messed with couple of configuration params.

Finally found that WPA2 does not affect to issues at all but speed need to be 54mb.

Now I've got lower speed, hope this won't affect skype calls (but it worked well with youtube (10xxp).

Comment: Changing the speed (mb) does not improve the range!

Comment: The issue is not about range. MPA can still connect to router but get big TTLs or sometimes no ping at all in the next room. And connection indicator shows 100%.